# Magento 2 - How to call Pre dispatch event on all front side pages?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, frontend

How to call **pre dispatch** event before **all** the **front-side** pages and it's action.

Let's say **Before** front side index page or product detail page is loaded, i want a event before all the **front-end action**.

Even before Index page load. How to achieve that ?

**Note:**

I want to call my dispatch event before all the front end actions, whenever any front action calls - **it should call my dispatch event first**.

Eg- Before Index page, CMS pages, every single front-end pages.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and Further clarification :) @TejabhagavanKollepara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use this for all page on front end.

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="<observername>" instance="<observerpath>" />
</event>
```

You can see in this file :

```
vendor/magento/module-persistent/etc/frontend/events.xml
```

It's same which you asked. It's call every time to checked customer session.

Comment: But can't we achieve it without changing in all front-end files ?

Comment: Not understand.

Comment: so should i override Magento\Persistent ?

Comment: Not sure but might be you can achieve using this.

Comment: Okay, let me try

Comment: Thanks Mitra :) your solution is working perfectly fine !!

Comment: Welcome bro anytime!!!!!